# Using best_in_place in different format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I wasn't quite sure how to title this.

I have installed and run and tested best_in_place and it is working perfectly. for example with:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :name %>
```

What I want to know is. How would I incorporate the best_in_place gem to the code below in order to edit item.amount, item.measurement etc...?

```
<ul>
  <% items.each do |item| %>
    <div class="ingredient-list">
      <li><%= "#{item.amount} #{item.measurement} #{item.ingredient.name} (#{item.notes})" %></li>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Have you tried just: `<li> <%= best_in_place(item, :amount)....</li>` ? My suggestion is that the instance variable `items` should be `@items.each` ...

Comment: Thanks for that. Late night got the better of me. I have changed items to @my_items which works. Adding in the best_in_place method as you said above brings this error now `undefined method 'item_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdfcfc3bbb0>:0x007fdfcfc39c48>` Any reason why?

Comment: I think it's better to post the code of your form (or view), just from `<ul>` fragment I cannot guess why. Assuming that `items` is a collection of objects of Item model , how do you invoke it in the corresponding `ItemsController` action? Does your `routes.rb` contain `resources :items` or similar?